# How do a dynamically switch parts of a pipe?

Tags: bash

I have a script which should execute a series of commands through a pipe. Depending of the arguments passed to the script:

- Either it encrypts the file, computes its hash, and sends it to a REST service.
- Or it compresses the file, computes its hash, and sends it to a REST service.
- Or it simply reads the file, computes its hash, and sends it to a REST service.

```
if [ "$encryption" = "GPG" ]; then
    gpg2 \
        --batch \
        --passphrase-file "$keyFile" \
        --output - \
        --symmetric \
        --compress-level "$compressLevel" \
        "$filePath" | \
        ./scripts/sha1.py --store "$sha1Destination" | \
        curl --silent -X PUT --limit-rate "$limitRate" "$uri" -F files[]=@-
elif [ "$encryption" = "disabled" ]; then
    if [ "$compressLevel" > 0 ]; then
        gzip --stdout "$filePath" -"$compressLevel" | \
        ./scripts/sha1.py --store "$sha1Destination" | \
        curl --silent -X PUT --limit-rate "$limitRate" "$uri" -F files[]=@-
    else
        cat "$filePath" | \
        ./scripts/sha1.py --store "$sha1Destination" | \
        curl --silent -X PUT --limit-rate "$limitRate" "$uri" -F files[]=@-
    fi
fi
```

The second and third part of each chain of commands remains the same: only the first part changes, being `gpg2` in one case, `gzip` in another, and `cat` in the last one.

I'm annoyed by the code duplication for the second and third part of the chain.

Is there a way to remove the code duplication, that is to do something like:

```
if [ "$encryption" = "GPG" ]; then
    ...
elif [ "$encryption" = "disabled" ]; then
    if [ "$compressLevel" > 0 ]; then
        ...
    else
        ...
    fi
fi

... | \
    ./scripts/sha1.py --store "$sha1Destination" | \
    curl --silent -X PUT --limit-rate "$limitRate" "$uri" -F files[]=@-
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can remove the code duplication.  Just put the pipe right after the `fi` and the pipe will capture *all* stdout from the `if` stmt.

This code (analogous to yours but much simplified) illustrates the point:

```
if [ "$a" = y ]
then
    echo abc1
else
    echo abc2
fi | sed 's/abc/ABC/'
```

The output from both `echo` statements is processed by the `sed` pipeline.

For example:

```
$ a=y; if [ "$a" = y ]; then echo abc1; else echo abc2; fi | sed 's/abc/ABC/'
ABC1
$ a=n; if [ "$a" = y ]; then echo abc1; else echo abc2; fi | sed 's/abc/ABC/'
ABC2
```